# What is the purpose of an "exec" call immediately after "fork"?

Tags: linux-kernel, exec, fork

Can anybody explain use of exec() call immmeditely after fork()? Is it avoid in making of seperate copy for child?

Comment: Without [fork/exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) (hint: search phrase), how would *you* launch another program as a child process? If exec is called immediately after the fork it is simply because nothing else needed to be done between the two. (Someone could likely quote portions of that wikipedia article for a "gimme point" answer ..)

Comment: You probably want to read here: http://www.evanjones.ca/fork-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 0):

`man exec` says that:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

while `man fork` says that:

> fork() creates a new process by duplicating the calling process.

So, the `fork-exec` chain means that the parent process `forking` a child by self duplicating and then replaces the current (childs) process image with the new one.

Note that it's not necessary to call `exec` after the `fork`. There are many cases where one process image serves parent and a child needs.